# Task list dataview web part xsl modification

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-designer, dataview, dataviewwebpart

My application is an apporval system.I am creating data view from a task list to show the current status of the doc, and grouping them based on title, if i take the count of items in each group title i get to call it as current level, If within a title group there are no task with status as 'Not started' I need to display that the title/doc is approved. It would be even better if i dont have to show such approved doc in my data view. How to achieve this in SPD by xsl editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i ended up with was simple...If there are no task with 'Not Started' status for a particular title it will display as Approved. For remaining title it will just display the group count...

```
<xsl:if test="count($nodeset[@Status='Not Started'])=0">Approved </xsl:if>
```